Misaligned dates for cross-day calculations
I have the following function that for a provided date and a pair of lat/long variables is supposed to return the the list of 3 timestamps in UTC

one in the afternoon on that day
one in the late evening on that day
and next one shortly before sunrise next day.

Unfortunately, likely because the calculations jump from one day to another, the results are totally off. Where I got this wrong? Is there a better approach to this?
import datetime as dt
from suntime import Sun

def key_timestamps(date, latitude, longitude):  
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    
    sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)
    
    sunrise = sun.get_sunrise_time(date)
    sunset = sun.get_sunset_time(date)
    
    next_day = date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    sunrise_next_day = sun.get_sunrise_time(next_day)
    
    solar_noon = sunrise + (sunset - sunrise) / 2
    peak_heating = solar_noon + dt.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)
    evening_release = sunset + dt.timedelta(hours=3)
    morning_minimum = sunrise_next_day - dt.timedelta(hours=1)
    
    return [
          int(peak_heating.timestamp()), 
          int(evening_release.timestamp()),
          int(morning_minimum.timestamp())
          ] 

singapore_results = key_timestamps("2022-05-29", 1.3521, 103.8198)
print(singapore_results)

Output is [1653809526, 1653746868, 1653947784] which translates to:

Sunday, May 29, 2022 7:32:06 AM - probably correct
Saturday, May 28, 2022 2:07:48 PM - should be a few hours later than #1 so totally wrong
Monday, May 30, 2022 9:56:24 PM - also wrong

Another example:
la_results = key_timestamps("2022-05-29", 34.0549, 118.2426)
Output:
[1653806070, 1653747048, 1653940656] which translates to:

Sunday, May 29, 2022 6:34:30 AM - wrong
Saturday, May 28, 2022 2:10:48 PM - wrong
Monday, May 30, 2022 7:57:36 PM - wrong


If you print sunrise and sunset for the Singapore example, you get: sunrise = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 29, 22, 56, 24, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
sunset = datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 28, 11, 7, 48, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc); it's probably a tz problem; you want to convert these utcs datetimes to local ones; perhaps have a look at https://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/toc.html


Sun.get_sunset_time() appears to return the sunset time from the previous day (even if you set the time component to 23:59:59) so to get today's sunset time you need to add 1 day.
You also may need to pass in a time-zone aware datetime and then use Sun.get_sunrise_time(date, tzinfo) (and for sunset) to ensure that the output has the correct time zone.

from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from suntime import Sun

def key_timestamps(date, latitude, longitude):  
    sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)
    
    sunrise = sun.get_sunrise_time(date, date.tzinfo)
    sunset = sun.get_sunset_time(date + timedelta(days=1), date.tzinfo)
    sunrise_next_day = sun.get_sunrise_time(date + timedelta(days=1), date.tzinfo)
    
    peak_heating = sunrise + (sunset - sunrise)/2 + timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)
    evening_release = sunset + timedelta(hours=3)
    morning_minimum = sunrise_next_day - timedelta(hours=1)
    
    return [peak_heating, evening_release, morning_minimum] 

singapore_results = key_timestamps(
    datetime(2022, 5, 29, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=ZoneInfo("Asia/Singapore")),
    1.3521,
    103.8198,
)
print(singapore_results)
print([int(t.timestamp()) for t in singapore_results])

Outputs:
[ datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 29, 15, 32, 6, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Singapore')),
  datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 29, 22, 7, 48, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Singapore')),
  datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 30, 5, 56, 24, tzinfo=zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Asia/Singapore'))]
[1653809526, 1653833268, 1653861384]


timestamp() will always return a UTC time no matter what timezone you have set in the datetime.

@MarkRansom I'm not sure what point you are trying to make as datetime.timestamp() is only used on the final line to generate the expected output to match the OP's question. The rest of the code propagates the correct time zones.

Just making sure everybody knows how timestamp() operates, we don't know what OP's expectations are.

@MTO thanks, the code works perfectly. I initially left here comments that it works for Singapore but doesn't for locations west from UTC but it just occurred to me that I was adding positive values for longitude while for the western hemisphere they should be negative. All good, many thanks!

import datetime as dt
from suntime import Sun
import pytz

def key_timestamps(date, latitude, longitude):
    # Parse the date and assume it's in local time
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d")
    
    # Sun calculation object
    sun = Sun(latitude, longitude)
    
    # Get sunrise and sunset in UTC
    sunrise_utc = sun.get_sunrise_time(date)
    sunset_utc = sun.get_sunset_time(date)
    
    # Convert date to the next day for the next sunrise
    next_day = date + dt.timedelta(days=1)
    sunrise_next_day_utc = sun.get_sunrise_time(next_day)
    
    # Calculate solar noon
    solar_noon = sunrise_utc + (sunset_utc - sunrise_utc) / 2
    
    # Calculate timestamps in UTC
    peak_heating_utc = solar_noon + dt.timedelta(hours=2, minutes=30)
    evening_release_utc = sunset_utc + dt.timedelta(hours=3)
    morning_minimum_utc = sunrise_next_day_utc - dt.timedelta(hours=1)
    
    # Return timestamps in UTC
    return [
        int(peak_heating_utc.timestamp()),
        int(evening_release_utc.timestamp()),
        int(morning_minimum_utc.timestamp())
    ]


where do you use pytz in this code?

Other than changing variable names, this is the same as the OP code.  It's just a code dump with no explanation.
